# Convert MySql Dump into h2db file

Tags: java, database, mysql, h2

Need to get a data from an sql dump into a h2 file db. Is there an easy way? Or some kind of transformation or a tool? Anything. thx for any help

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few [tools](http://h2database.com/html/links.html#tools) that are specialised to migrate data from one database to another:

- [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/), agile database migration framework for Java.
- [SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin](http://dbcopyplugin.sf.net/), a tool to copy data from one database to another.

Comment: FYI Flyway cannot do this, unless the statements in the dump are compatible with H2.

Comment: Is there any tools to migrate Mysql script into h2?